# Install Donkey car Python TensorFlow - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

use Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 2GB
Raspbian BULLSEYE (DEBIAN 11) ARMV71
package name "2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-armhf-full"

i try Install Donkeycar Python Code from official website when I enter installation code

```
pip install https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v2.2.0/tensorflow-2.2.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

Error: donkeycar tensorflow-2.2.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS you can install Tensorflow in the standard way - pip3 install tensorflow. The 64-bit system comes with a reasonably recent version of python 3 preinstalled (3.8 maybe? - I can't remember exactly), so you can just create a virtual environment and go.

That's how I remember it anyway - I'm hoping I'm not forgetting some obstacle.

It appeared to work OK to me, but it's slow - much slower than on an x86 cpu.

I never managed to install Tensorflow on 32-bit Raspbian. And conda didn't seem to work either - I think it assumes a higher ARM spec than the Pi uses.

[Edited to add...] After checking, I think you may need to pip install tensorflow-aarch64, not standard tensorflow.